# jQuery using multiple selectors on a radio field

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I have the following html element that I would to select by using both the name AND value - can anyone illustrate how I would do this:

```
<input type="radio" value="check" name="payment_method">
```

The following works.. but only for a single attribute, I would like to match both the value & name:

```
$('input[value="check"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Essentially I am trying to say check this if value='check' AND name='payment'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the [Multiple Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/) and the [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method:

```
$('input[value="check"][name="payment_method"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: @Zabs: Yes, **as of jQuery 1.6**, the `.prop()` method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `.attr()` retrieves attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You can add multiple attributes to the selector, and always use `prop()` when setting properties like `element.checked` :

```
$('input[name="payment_method"][value="check"]').prop('checked', true);
```